# Database connection pooling

Tags: ruby, database, sinatra

I created a small chat application in Sinatra and jQuery on heroku. It simply inserts a message to a database when user submits it. And also downloads new messages every 2 seconds. After a few minutes of testing it stopped working and I received an email form heroku:

> Hi,
>
> We noticed that the gisekchat app had a large number of connections
>   open to the shared database. We had to limit the number of connections
>   to the shared database due to performance reasons. Can you either
>   reduce the number of overall connections to the shared db or move to a
>   dedicated database?
>
> It does appear that you're not taking advantage of connection pooling
>   and are opening a new connection to the database for each request from
>   your app.
>
> Thanks,
>   -Chris

This is the action supporting submitting a message (receiving is very similar):

```
post '/send' do
  con = con = PGconn.connect($dbhost, 5432, "","",$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass)
  con.exec("insert into messages(usr, msg, date) values('#{params[:usr]}','#{params[:msg]}', now())")    
end
```

How should I change it to enable connection pooling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah well it's true, you really are opening a new connection to the database each time there is a 'send'-post send.

So you'll need to change that. One Possibility may be, to open the connection globally:

```
 $con = PGconn.connect($dbhost, 5432, "","",$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass)
```

This should be done after you initialized your $dbname... variables, but before you use any routes.

However, if you are using the modular sinatra version, instead of the classic one, you could declare an instance variable with

```
attr_accessor :con
```

and initialize it before the app is started.

Answer (score 4):

Robustus is halfway there
creating an instance variable will create a connection for each instance of your class.

What you want is a thread-safe data store api that will use a mutex to handle access to your connection object(s).  This is the control mechanism that ActiveRecord uses in rails.

I have created a ruby gem called 'q' that provides a simple mechanism for doing this.
The gem is located here:
https://github.com/jacobsimeon/q

install like this
`git clone https://github.com/jacobsimeon/q`

then add this to whatever file initializes your app:
`require 'q/resourcepool'`

then, create your datastore during initialization:

```
class DataConnection < ResourcePool
  def create_resource
    PGConn.connect(@config)
  end
end
@datasource = ResourcePool.new(your_connection_info_here)
```

then, you can use @datasource to execute commands against your database

```
post '/send' do
  @datasource.exec(standard_postgres_params)
end
```

Contact me on github or twitter (@jacobsimeon on both) if you're interested in going this route.

Comment: yeah that seems about right, if thread-safety is something you need to achieve, but this is normally something you could only do in the modular version, not in the classic one (afaik)

Comment: From the looks of the example code, it looks like we're dealing with a sinatra app. I'm not certain, but I think every request comes through a new thread on heroku's free hosting.
What did you mean by "modular version"?

Comment: there are two different versions of writing a sinatra app. The classic one, where the 'main' file contains the routes and operation, e.g. no instance variable, and the modular one, where you implement a class inhereting from Sinatra::Base

Comment: The instance variable would still be available wouldn't it?  The scope would just be far wider if you're not subclassing Sinatra::Base

Comment: in my experience the scope wouldn't pertain to the routes..., but maybe i did something wrong

Comment: If you define the ivar outside of a Sinatra method, you're defining it as an ivar to Kernel, which makes it accessible from pretty much anywhere. That said, I'd suggest going the "modular" route anyhow.

Comment: jacob, actually i tested it right now, if you declare in a classic environment an instance variable out of a `get ... end` block you won't be able to use it inside the `get ... end` block.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the 'classic' sinatra application and I've obtained the same result by declaring class variables : e.g @@db_connection. This always uses the same connection and works for me.