# Heroku PostgreSQL database connection pooling in Ruby for Rack with Puma

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, connection-pooling, rack

UPDATE: I tried changing the storage of the PostgreSQL connection object from a constant `POSTGRES` to a class variable `@@pg`. That didn't fix the issue. Then, I tried changing it to a global variable `$pg`. That seems to have worked! I still would like to eventually implement database connection pooling, however, so that I can have a pool of up to 5 (or so) database connections handling requests instead of just one global connection for all requests. END UPDATE

I'm hosting the [Acani Chats REST Server](https://github.com/acani/Chats-Server-REST) on Heroku.

The first request works OK, but subsequent requests fail to connect to the PostgreSQL database.

I get the following errors:

`Rack app error: #<PG::UnableToSend: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac>`

`Rack app error: #<PG::UnableToSend: no connection to the server>`

What's going on?

In [`/config/application.rb`](https://github.com/acani/Chats-Server-REST/blob/master/config/application.rb), I define the constant `POSTGRES` to be the PostgreSQL connection object.

Should I be using a global or class variable instead of a constant to hold onto the connection instance?

In [`/config/routes.rb`](https://github.com/acani/Chats-Server-REST/blob/master/config/routes.rb), I define the Rack `call` method.

I want to learn how to implement [database connection pooling in Ruby for Rack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971832/database-connection-pooling) with Puma and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puma is threaded so you need a thread safe pool of connections to PostgreSQL, otherwise concurrent requests will all use the same connection concurrently, which is unexpected.

Please have a look to the [connection_pool](https://rubygems.org/gems/connection_pool) gem. It should help.